# Creating a method which returns a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I'm working on learning java the hard way, banging my head and understanding how to do things the difficult way.  So this may be impossible, however, is it possible to make a method which returns a 2D Array of type String?

Specifically this is a method which prompts the user to input a list of first and last names which is in a 2D array.

```
public static String nameTest() {
    String nameList[][] = new String[publicArraySize][publicArraySize];

            //get user names here

    return nameList;  <--gives error can't convert from String[][] to String
    }
```

Again this is to get the list of names in a 2D array.  Then step 2 is to return that string array in a method.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Change `public static String nameTest()` --> `public static String[][] nameTest()`

Comment: This might help you understand more: (Number 2 in particular) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but in your code you need to make the method signature String[][] too(give more codes to check if other line are wrong). Beside you could create a new object "Name" and fill fields such as FirstName and LastName, and then add them in an ArraList each time you provide one.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I had attempted this before but I must have had errors every time some how or misunderstood how Eclipse worked.

Answer (score 0):

This line: `public static String nameTest()` is the method signature. It's like a contract and you have to follow this contract.

1. `public` -> It means that the method can be called from any class.
2. `static` -> It means that the method is static.
3. `String` -> It means that the method will return an object of the String type. The problem is that you are trying to return a bidimensional String array instead.
4. `()` -> It means that the method has no parameters. So, you can't call this method using arguments.

To solve your problem, you have to change the return type from String to String[][] in this way:

```
public static String[][] nameTest() {
    String nameList[][] = new String[publicArraySize][publicArraySize];

            //get user names here

    return nameList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I need to say, a basic rule of function define is the type of the function should be the same type with the return value.
This means if you define your function as

```
public static String nameTest(){}
```

your return value should be String.

To fix this error, you need to change your function to

```
public static String[][] nameTest() {
    String nameList[][] = new String[publicArraySize][publicArraySize];

            //get user names here

    return nameList;  <--gives error can't convert from String[][] to String
    }
```